# Terraform Azure_Linux_VM makes SSH key not work

Tags: azure, ssh, terraform

How do I ssh into my newly created Azure_VM via SSH?

I am setting up a simple VM via Terraform, assigning it a public IP and an SSH key which I have locally.
Using the tutorial from the terraform page itself: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
...
  admin_username = "adminuser"

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

[...]
}
```

However, after Terraform has created the machine, I can not log into the machine.

`$ ssh adminuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
yields:

```
adminuser@137.117.168.115: Permission denied (publickey).
```

---

**Tried**:
First I thought it was the wrong public key. So I checked the public_key on the machine with:

```
az vm list --query "[].{SSH: 
osProfile.linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys[].keyData}" -o json
```

and compared it to my public key on my local machine.
They are the same, except for ONE "\n" that is printed in the Azure-VM output.
Adding a new line to my local public key however did not fix the issue.

**The Catch**:
Sometimes, after destroying the machine and rebulding it I can login. After and additional `terraform destroy` and `terraform apply` it doesn't work anymore. I don
t get what I am doing wrong

So, how do I get to SSH into my newly created VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did overwrite the default (`adminuser`) with a cloud_init config.
After adding the **default** user to the cloud_config I could connect via SSH to adminuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

```
 data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {                                     
   gzip = true                                                                   
   base64_encode = true                                                          
                                                                                 
   part {                                                                        
     content_type = "text/cloud-config"                                          
     content      = "users: [default, foobar, barfoo]"
   }                                                                             
 }
```